# directive doesn't function properly

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a directive which limits the input of the user. On the example `limit-directive="2"`, the user can only type two characters in the input field.

My problem is that my directive is not working. It is invoked but doesn't stop the key press with return false or also `event.preventDefault();`.
Any ideas on what am I missing ?

```
export class limitDirective implements angular.IDirective {
        restrict = 'A';

        constructor() {
            if(console) console.log('limit directive invoked')
        }

        link = (scope: angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitDirective);

            angular.element(element).on("keypress", function(event) {
                if (this.value.length >= limit){
                    var allowedKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46];
                    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;

                    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(key) < 0 ){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        static factory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {
            const directive = () => new limitDirective();
            return directive;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? My guess is that you have to use the `keydown` event instead of `keypress`. Also you might want to explicitly specify the radix for `parseInt` like `parseInt(number, 10)` since older versions of EcmaScript use the octal as a default radix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a if is `less than or equals` to operator instead of the `greater that or equals`. And i doubt that `this` correspond to the element in the callback of the event.. I suggest you do:

```
 element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                if (element[0].value.length <= limit){
                    var allowedKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46];
                    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
                if (allowedKeys.indexOf(key) < 0 ){
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

            }
        });
```